# Returning all rows that don't contain a certain value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Example data frame:

```
> df <- data.frame(A = c('a', 'b', 'c'), B = c('c','d','e'))
> df
  A B
1 a c
2 b d
3 c e
```

The following returns all rows in which any value is "c"

```
> df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. == "c"))
  A B
1 a c
2 c e
```

How do I return the inverse of this, all rows in which no value is ever "c"? In this example, that would be row 2 only. **Tidyverse solutions preferred, thanks.**

EDIT: To be clear, I am asking about exact matching, I don't care if a value contains a "c", just if the value is exactly "c".

Comment: Oh, that's good, thanks. I wasn't even thinking about base R tbh. Still would be curious about a dplyr solution but this is fine

Comment: `df %>% filter_all(all_vars(. != "c"))`, but is superseded, see @r2evans.

Comment: @harre I had tried that before I posted and I thought it hadn't worked because I was only looking at row counts. But actually that was because every row that had a "c" also had an NA somewhere so it returned the whole row as all NAs. How do I tell this to ignore NAs?

Comment: I cannot replicate that problem in my end using `df <- data.frame(A = c(NA, 'b', 'c', NA), B = c('c','d','e', NA))`, it still seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I was trying `df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. != "c"))`  instead of `df %>% filter_all(all_vars(. != "c"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### dplyr

FYI, `filter_all` has been superseded by the use of `if_any` or `if_all`.

```r
df %>%
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ . != "c"))
#   A B
# 1 b d
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining the syntax here? In particular I don't understand what `~` and `.` are doing together.

Comment: The `~` starts an "rlang function", though is technically using R's formula. The `.` there represents the data (one column at a time), so `~ . != "c"` is equivalent to `function(x) x != "c"` (or `\(x) x != "c"` in R-4's newer syntax).

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to use **dplyr**?

```
df[rowSums(df == 'c') == 0, ]
#  A B
#2 b d
```

---

*Adding OP's comments into answer*

This works for me, thank you. My original issue was that any row with a "c" somewhere also had an NA somewhere else, so the adapted solution is

```
df[rowSums(df == 'c', na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]
```

Honestly this is more readable than **dplyr** syntax. But as I asked for a **dplyr** solution, I accepted another answer.

Comment: I guess I don' t mind my comment being added to the answer, but I did say it's more readable *to me*,  I can't speak for others

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A = c('a', 'b', 'c', NA, 'c'), B = c('c','d','e', 'g', NA))

     A    B
1    a    c
2    b    d
3    c    e
4 <NA>    g
5    c <NA>

df %>% filter_all(all_vars(. != "c" | is.na(.)))

     A B
1    b d
2 <NA> g
```

Comment: Oops my previous comment is wrong so I deleted it. This works. What I was missing is that this answer has `all_vars` and before I posted I had tried `filter_all(any_vars(. != "c"))`

Comment: @BenS. I updated my code based on your previous comments regarding how this code would work if missing values are in the data.